# Ajax json Parser Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parse-error

I keep on getting a JSON parser error 
(firebug console say 'There are no child objects') for the following data:

(String) var data from each iteration

```
var data='['; 
data+=   '{ "title": "  Nac", "no1": "1212","no2": "12126"},';
data+=   '{ "title": "  Nac", "no1": "1212","no2": "12126"},';
data+=   '{ "title": "  Nac", "no1": "1212","no2": "12126"},';
data+= ']';
```

and javascript parsing json

```
var json = JSON.parse(data)
```

and jQuery AJAX request

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: json,
        url : 'ticket.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) 
        {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) 
            {
                $('.item').html("err");
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) 
            {
                $('.item').html('err!');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) 
            {
                alert("err!");
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') 
            {
                $('.item').html('err parsererror');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') 
            {
                $('.item').html('err!');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') 
            {
                $('.item').html('err!');
            } else 
            {
            $('.item').html('err!');
            }
        },
        success : function(data)
        {
            alert("okey");
        }           
    });
```

and ticket.php is completely empty because I don't no how receive json data from ajax in php

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thnks

Comment: I just tried `JSON.parse` on it and it worked okay

Comment: No need to parse if you already set datatype=json.. Because it will already parse the JSON string as a javascript object

Comment: tha parsing error is because of the ,(comma) after the last  object of the string   ie after the last '{ "title": "  Nac", "no1": "1212","no2": "12126"}' you have to concatenate data with **]** and not **,]**

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` gives you a JavaScript object, if you're sending `json` in a post then send json not an object. Also instead of building a json string, build an object and then stringify it

```
var data= [{
    "title": "  Nac",
    "no1": "1212",
    "no2": "12126"
},
{
    "title": "New",
    "no1": "12",
    "no2": "121"
},
{
    "title": "San",
    "no1": "1227",
    "no2": "1"
}];
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: json,
        url : 'ticket.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        ...
```